# How can I get Perl's LWP to fetch English versions of web pages?

Tags: perl, http-headers

I am using the [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple) module in Perl. Using the `getstore` function, I download the content of the given URL into a file. Sometimes the language of the URL is non-English, even though when I load the URL into the browser, I see the English translation of this content. How do I get the English translation every time instead of the original content? Are there any options to the `getstore` function to do this, or is there any other Perl function to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That is part of [HTTP content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation#The_Accept-Language.3A_header). You'll need to use [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) to specify the appropriate headers with the request.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are referring to both the "web-address" as well as actual "content" on the page. I think its more about your approach that you need to fix.

If an URL is in non-english, it still points to the same IP-ADDRESS if its a valid web-address. So just write a function to detect language and convert the address to its IP-Address.

If its about the actual content of the website. You have to first figure how the website in question stores its different versions of that page. A common way is similar to this:

**en**.example.com

**es**.example.com

**in**.example.com

In that case, all you have to do is fetch the correct content using the said URL, something like this:

```
my $c = "en.example.com"
```

But if the page is not translated in advance, than it might become a bit complex. You need to translate the page using a online translator or something. Perhaps check out Google Translate API.